# Curly Brackets added to formula in Excel workbook when downloading from a Google Sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, formula

I have a Google Sheet Workbook with the following formula:

`=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A8,'Budget Ids'!A2, 'Budget Ids'!C2), "")`

The above formula works in the Google Sheet. When I download the Google Sheet as a Microsoft Excel workbook and then click "Enable Editing", I get this:

`{=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(A9,'Budget Ids'!A3, 'Budget Ids'!C3), "")}`

It wraps my entire formula in curly brackets. If I click into the cell, the brackets go away and the value from my formula appears. But I don't understand why the curly brackets are being added when I download it as a Microsoft Excel workbook and how to fix it as opposed to manually clicking into the cell. As far as I know, `IFERROR` and `XLOOKUP` are valid functions in both Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: commenting for visibility

Comment: The File/Download feature in Google Sheets appears to generate an Excel file which is initially interpreted with respect to the functionality of an earlier version of Excel (2010?), even if that file is opened in a later version of Excel. If you remove the `IFERROR` part of your formula and download to Excel again, you'll see that it results in a `#NAME?` error, since `XLOOKUP` did not exist in Excel until recently. Ditto for any other new function. Recommitting the formula with `ENTER` will force a correct resolution, however.

Comment: I assume that Excel is also interpreting the Google Sheets formula as a legacy array formula, thus adding the curly brackets, though I'm not sure why this is the case.

Comment: [XLOOKUP is not available in Excel 2016 and Excel 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929). I agree with @JosWoolley and Excel is reading it as an array formula.  *how to fix it as opposed to manually clicking into the cell* Do this just on the first cell and then double click on the  *Fill Handle* to overwrite all formulas in same column with no Curly Brackets. Or change the formula to make it compatible with your Excel version (Google Sheets **is not** the same than Excel. Very similar but different softwares).

Comment: I found a workaround. Not the best fan of it but it works:

=IFERROR(INDEX('Budget Ids'!C:C,MATCH(A8,'Budget Ids'!A:A,0), ""))

I converted it into an INDEX with a MATCH function within the Google Sheet instead of XLOOKUP . When I download it as an Excel workbook, the formula goes away BUT the numbers do stay. If the stakeholder's are downloading it as an Excel than rather than a Google Sheet, my assumption is they won't need the formula as they'll just need static numbers.

Comment: @runner16 Have you tried using the formulas with no named ranges? I mean, instead of `Budget ids` use the address of those cells (something like `A2:A100`)

Comment: Nah, that still doesn't work. I'm going to stick with the INDEX MATCH function instead. That seems to be doing the trick for me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

What a weird problem this is.  A VBA solution is to select one of the cells in the block and run this VBA macro:

```
Sub GetRidOfStupidBrackets()

'this assumes you have one of the cells in the block selected
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Value = Selection.FormulaR1C1

End Sub
```

This is like clicking on each cell, pressing F2 to edit it and then pressing ENTER (which solves the problem).